# What is the type erasure of "?"?

Tags: java, generics

If I have the following method:

```
public <U extends Number> void doSomething(List<U> l){      
}
```

Then due to `type erasure` the compiler will make it to `doSomething(List<Number> l)`. Right?
If this is the case, then why it is not possible to declare the following along with this:

```
public void doSomething(List<?> l){  
}
```

Isn't this second method, `type erased` to `doSomething(List<Object> l)`? Why do I get compiler error of same erasure for these 2 methods?

Comment: You could have actual types as a work around:  public void setList(StringList strings) {
 }

 public void setList(List<?> obs) {
 }

 private class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {
 }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your thinking is wrong. Erasure leads to both methods having this signature (`List` argument types being erased):

```
public void doSomething(List l) {  
}
```

Hence, the collision. What you thought was possible to do is this:

```
public <U extends Number> void doSomething(U argument) {      
}  
public <U extends Object> void doSomething(U argument) {      
}
```

In this case, after erasure, the method signatures will become this (after `U` having been erased)

```
public void doSomething(Number argument) {      
}  
public void doSomething(Object argument) {      
}
```

In this case, there is no signature collision.

Comment: So `List` is kept and the type parameters from list erased?

Comment: @user384706: Precisely. You can verify this in byte code or using reflection

Comment: I hadn't reallized that.Do you have a reference on this I could read?

Comment: @user384706: This is well explained in the tutorials, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: I have seen this and I don't think it is that clear.It says: `Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds`.For me I understand that it is the `List<U extends Number>` that is replaced by `List<Number>` and not that `List<U extends Number>` is replaced by `List`.What am I reading wrong?

Comment: Check out this sub-page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html. It explains how things happen when `Node` is parameterised with a bound. If you think about it, it is really logical. `List<Number>` is still a generic type, not a raw type. Hence, type erasure is not yet complete. By your (informal) reasoning, you'd still have to erase `<Number>`

Comment: It seems same issue to me. `T extends Comparable<T>` is erased to `Comparable`. And `U extends Number` I was expecting to be erased by a `Number`. How is it similar to my example?May be I am not reading this correctly?

Comment: Look closely. `T` is "erased" to `Comparable`. `Node<T>` is "erased" to `Node`. What else should the resulting *raw type* of `Node<T>` be?

Comment: I see now.But in this example the type i.e. `Comparable` is retained by the compiler in `Node`.In my example where `List<U extends Number>` becomes `List` the type about `Number` is being lost?

Comment: `U => T`, `Number => Comparable`, `List => Node`. It's exactly the same example as yours! I can't help you more than that... Just think about these examples some more, and understand that `T` and `SomeType<T>` are not the same things to begin with... It's just how erasure works

Answer (score 2):

[`?`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) is used as wildcard in generics.

It will be erased.

`U extends Number` tells that upper bound is Number

`List<?>` doesn't tell what is upper bound.

EDIT: Based on edited question, after compilation, byte code just contains.

```
public void doSomething(List argument) {      
}  
public void doSomething(List argument) {      
}
```

[Inheritance in generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) is little different than what we know as inheritance in java.

Comment: Ok.So?Isn't it somehow erased as well?

Comment: `U extends Number` doesn't mean that the compiler will convert the parameter to `Number`?

Comment: So if I am correct that the first method will be transformed to `doSomething(List<Number> l)` by the compiler, then why is there a name clash with `doSomething(List<?> l)`?

Comment: At runtime they both appear the same. List without generic.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**  `?` is used as wild card in Generics.

**Eg:**

Assume **Animal is a Class**.

`ArrayList<? extends Animal>`  means **Any Class's instance which extends Animal**

During the `Erasure`, **which is a process in which Compiler removes the Generics in Class and Methods during the Compilation time**, to make the Generics code compatible to the one which was written when Generics were not introduced.

So `?` and `U` will be removed during `compilation` time.. so **during runtime it will be absent**

Comment: I am not asking what is `?`. I am asking why is the type erasure the same for these 2 methods